# Date comparison returns unusual result - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic, to-date

I have a table of the structure:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
| week_no | long_week_no | week_start_date | week_end_date | month | year |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
| 1       | 1A           | 01/01/2015      | 03/01/2015    | JAN   | 2015 |
| 1       | 1B           | 04/01/2015      | 10/01/2015    | JAN   | 2015 |
| 2       | 2            | 11/01/2015      | 17/01/2015    | JAN   | 2015 |
| 3       | 3            | 18/01/2015      | 24/01/2015    | JAN   | 2015 |
| ..      | ..           | ..              | ..            | ..    | ..   |
| 51      | 51           | 14/12/2014      | 20/12/2015    | DEC   | 2014 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
```

When I run the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   loy_period 
WHERE  To_date('15/04/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN 
       To_date(week_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
       To_date(week_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM   loy_period 
WHERE  To_date('15/04/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN 
       week_start_date AND 
       week_end_date;
```

It returns the following:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
| week_no | long_week_no | week_start_date | week_end_date | month | year |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
|      51 | 51           | 14/12/2014      | 20/12/2015    | DEC   | 2014 |
|       1 | 1A           | 01/01/2015      | 03/01/2015    | JAN   | 2015 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-------+------+
```

And when I run it with any date, it will return the correct period *in addition to* the week_no 51 record!

I'm confused why this is happening. Both columns `week_start_date` and `week_end_date` of the type `date`.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5bc9/1) works as expected.

Comment: If they're already of type `date`, why on earth are you calling `To_Date` on them?

Comment: And, in fact: [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm): "Do not use the TO_DATE function with a DATE value for the char argument"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I ran without `To_Date` and it returns the same result.

Comment: Never use TO_DATE on a DATE column. It will implicitly convert it into string and then back to date using locale-specific NLS format.

Comment: Can you put your sample data and a sane version of your query into [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Are you sure the year is correct in row 51?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, the year is 2014. Sorry for missing that out. I updated it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've added http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5bc9/1

Comment: You need to work on that fiddle until it a) exhibits the *problem* you're asking for help with or b) You spot the issue yourself.

Comment: I always wonder why so many people think they need to use `to_date()` to convert a `date` into a `date`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the hint. I did not expect it could be wrong insert into the table. I now understand the result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'll be honest, I used it thinking I need to force some date format. I do not remember exactly what I read somewhere that date format stored in the DB is different than the one we see in the tables (which follows the session format). Maybe this is irrelevant. But chance for me to learn

Comment: @hawk, no problem. You learned something good today. Read this good blog post by Ed Stevens on Date https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: Dates don't have a format. Any format you see is applied by the application displaying the data

Comment: @LalitKumarB I'll read it carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly for me with *proper* use of **TO_DATE** and DATE values.

- Never use **TO_DATE** on a **DATE**, It will *implicitly convert it into string and then back to date using locale-specific NLS format*.
- `'01/01/2015'` is NOT a DATE, it is a STRING. You must use **TO_DATE** to explicitly convert it into DATE.

See what happens:

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from dual where to_date(sysdate) > to_date(sysdate -1);

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3752461848

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!))>TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!-1)))

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, the actual filter applied is **filter(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!))** You will get incorrect output due to the implicit conversion based on locale-specific NLS format.

Anyway, now coming back to your original question.

For example,

Let's say your data looks like:

**Setup:**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2      (week_no VARCHAR2(2), long_week_no VARCHAR2(2), week_start_date DATE, week_end_date DATE, mnth VARCHAR2(3), yr VARCHAR2(4))
  3  ;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO t (week_no, long_week_no, week_start_date, week_end_date, mnth, yr)
  3           VALUES ('1', '1A', TO_DATE('01/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('03/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'JAN', '2015')
  4      INTO t (week_no, long_week_no, week_start_date, week_end_date, mnth, yr)
  5           VALUES ('1', '1B', TO_DATE('04/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('10/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'JAN', '2015')
  6      INTO t (week_no, long_week_no, week_start_date, week_end_date, mnth, yr)
  7           VALUES ('2', '2', TO_DATE('11/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('17/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'JAN', '2015')
  8      INTO t (week_no, long_week_no, week_start_date, week_end_date, mnth, yr)
  9           VALUES ('3', '3', TO_DATE('18/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('24/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'JAN', '2015')
 10      INTO t (week_no, long_week_no, week_start_date, week_end_date, mnth, yr)
 11           VALUES ('51', '51', TO_DATE('20/12/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('26/12/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DEC', '2014')
 12  SELECT * FROM dual
 13  ;

5 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

**Table:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

WE LO WEEK_STAR WEEK_END_ MNT YR
-- -- --------- --------- --- ----
1  1A 01-JAN-15 03-JAN-15 JAN 2015
1  1B 04-JAN-15 10-JAN-15 JAN 2015
2  2  11-JAN-15 17-JAN-15 JAN 2015
3  3  18-JAN-15 24-JAN-15 JAN 2015
51 51 20-DEC-14 26-DEC-15 DEC 2014

SQL>
```

**Query to filter the rows based on DATE range:**

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   t
  3  WHERE  To_date('15/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN
  4         week_start_date AND
  5         week_end_date;

WE LO WEEK_STAR WEEK_END_ MNT YR
-- -- --------- --------- --- ----
2  2  11-JAN-15 17-JAN-15 JAN 2015
51 51 20-DEC-14 26-DEC-15 DEC 2014

SQL>
```