# compare datetime in oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, compare

I have a commands as below:

```
to_char(to_date('req_date','yyyy/mm/dd'),'yyyymmdd) > '20140401'; is success
```

But after when I have changed year from 2014 to 2015 , have a error format string.
As below

```
to_char(to_date('req_date','yyyy/mm/dd'),'yyyymmdd) > '20150401';
```

I don't know that is error.Let's fix for me.
Thanks for all

Comment: These are not actually your commands, are they? At least one quote is missing, and `req_date` is quoted so it's not a valid date. Please copy-paste the actual commands.

Comment: Never use TO_DATE on a DATE, It will implicitly convert it into string and then back to date using locale-specific NLS format. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29559609/3989608

Answer (score 0):

> to_char(to_date('req_date','yyyy/mm/dd'),'yyyymmdd) > '20140401';

1. `'req_date'` is not a date, it is a string. You don't need single-quotation marks, use the date column as it is.
2. Never use **TO_DATE** on a **DATE**, It will implicitly convert it into string and then back to date using locale-specific NLS format. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559609/3989608
3. Most importantly, you are comparing two **STRINGS**. You need to compare the **DATE**s. You need to leave the date as it is for DATE calculations. **TO_CHAR** is for display, and **TO_DATE** is to convert a string literal into DATE.

So, you need to do the date comparison as:

```
req_date > to_date('20140401','YYYYMMDD')
```