# Unable to convert varchar2 to Date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

I am trying to convert one of the varchar2 column to date in oracle using      the below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM login
WHERE to_date(END_DATE,'DD-MM-YY') < to_date(TRUNC(SYSDATE)-90,'DD-MM-YY');
```

I am converting the both side to date with a common formatter. But  still I am getting the below error while executing this query.

```
 ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
  01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
 *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
       the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
       "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
       with no extra whitespace.
 *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal
```

Can you please help me to sort out this problem?

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: @Jens  I have shared the query which I am trying to execute. My column will be having value/data like... 14-Mar-2015.And the query Select SYSDATE from dual  is giving me data in 28-05-15 format. So I am formaating both the date to  DD-MM-YY.

Comment: Try to use `MON` instat of `MM` in to to_date

Comment: Does SELECT end_date FROM login shows the date as 14-Mar-2015? IF so you need MON to format string instead MM.

Comment: @Pushpa why did you tag `sqlserver2008`? The error clearly shows you use `Oracle`.

Answer (score 1):

> to_date(END_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')

- First of all, it is a *bad design* to store **DATE** as **STRING**. Date should always be stored as DATE data type, there is no reason to store it as characters.
- If your data is stored as `14-Mar-2015` then why are you using the `'DD-MM-YY'` format. Clearly the formats doesn't match. You should use proper **format model**.

For example,

```
TO_DATE(14-Mar-2015,'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

> to_date(TRUNC(SYSDATE)-90,'DD-MM-YY')

- This makes no sense. **TRUNC** on **DATE** would return you DATE after truncating the time portion.
- *Never ever use* **TO_DATE** on **DATE**. *It will implicitly convert it into string and then back to date using* **locale-specific NLS format**. See a detailed explanation in my previous answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559609/3989608

Your modified query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM login
WHERE to_date(END_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') < TRUNC(SYSDATE)-90;
```

Comment: I have changed my query to   Select * from login where TO_DATE(END_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') < TRUNC(SYSDATE) -90 ; Still getting the same error

Comment: @Pushpa Why did you store date as string? Are all the values in the same format like `14-mar-2015`? Post some sample data.

Comment: what is the datatype of your end_date column? If it's DATE or TIMESTAMP, then as Lalit mentioned, you wouldn't put to_date around it.

Comment: @Boneist Actually OP said it's varchar2 in the question. So, I assume that there are values with different format which is causing the issue. i would not allow such a design ;-)

Comment: @Pushpa Execute the follwoing query and let me know if it throws error `SELECT to_date(END_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') FROM login`

Comment: @LalitKumarB this will work fine.. I believe the problem is coming because the left hand side date format and right hand side date format is not matching..

Comment: @Pushpa DATE doesn't have any format. What you see is only for display for human readable format.