# date comparison oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

how to compare joining date with current date and if it is less than or equal to 45 days then select those details and display in oracle sql, what to do if joining date and current date in different format like (joining date `12/03/2015` and current date `01-MAR-17`)?

Comment: Date doesn't have any format. It is only displayed in a format you could understand based on your locale specific NLS settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059638/3989608

Comment: share your table schema/structure and what have you tried yet

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this (if you need rows for those who joined 45 days or more ago):

```
select *
from your_table
where joining_date <= trunc(sysdate) - 45;
```

Answer (score -1):

I luckily  got output, query is

`select COL_NAME from TABLE_NAME where (to_date(SYSDATE)- to_date(COL_NAME,'dd/mm/yyyy'))<=60`

Comment: **Never** apply `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. `to_date()` expects a `varchar` so the date value will first be converted to a `varchar` then passed to the `to_date()` function which will convert it back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559609/3989608 As @a_horse_with_no_name said, **Never use TO_DATE on a DATE, It will implicitly convert it into string and then back to date using locale-specific NLS format.**

Comment: A second issue with this query is that it won't use an index (if there is one) on `COL_NAME` - for that you want `WHERE col_name >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-60)`